# Injecting mock before Spring's post-construct phase

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

Basically, the question is in the title. 
I faced a problem that in post-construct phase my bean (that is autowired in the bean that is going through post-construct phase right now) is already mocked, but all the behavior described by `Mockito.when()` doesn't work, all the calls return `null`.

While searching I found [this](http://www.therore.net/java/2015/06/06/injecting-mockito-mocks-into-the-spring-context.html) solution.

But is it possible to make it work without using any 3rd party libraries?

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class ServiceTest {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("test")
private PCLPortType pclPortType;

@MockBean
private ClearingHelper сlearingHelper;

@MockBean
private OrganizationCacheRepository organizationCacheRepository;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception{

     OperationResultWithOrganizationSystemIdMappingList res = new OperationResultWithOrganizationSystemIdMappingList();

    when(clearingHelper.getOrgIdSystemIdMapping(any(Keycloak.class))).thenReturn(res);
}


@Test
public void test() throws Exception{
    pclPortType.call("123");
}
}
```

Test config:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestApplicationConfiguration {

@Bean(name = "test")
public PCLPortType pclPortTypeForTest() throws JAXBException {
   ...
}

@Bean
public Keycloak keycloak() {
    return Mockito.mock(Keycloak.class);
}
}
```

Component where I want to get mocked beans:

```
@Component
public class OrganizationCacheJob {
private static final Logger logger = 
LogManager.getLogger(OrganizationCacheJob.class);

private final ObjectFactory<Keycloak> factory;
private final ClearingHelper clearingHelper;
private final OrganizationCacheRepository organizationCacheRepository;

@Autowired
public OrganizationCacheJob(ObjectFactory<Keycloak> factory,
                            ClearingHelper clearingHelper,
                            OrganizationCacheRepository organizationCacheRepository) {
    this.factory = factory;
    this.clearingHelper = ClearingHelper;
    this.organizationCacheRepository = organizationCacheRepository;
}


@PostConstruct
public void updateCacheRepository() {
    doUpdateCacheRepository();
}

@Scheduled(cron = "${organization.cache.schedule}")
public void start() {
    logger.info("Starting update organization cache.");
    doUpdateCacheRepository();
    logger.info("Job finished.");
}

private void doUpdateCacheRepository() {
    try {
        Keycloak keycloak = factory.getObject();
        OperationResultWithOrganizationSystemIdMappingList orgIdSystemIdMapping = clearingHelper.getOrgIdSystemIdMapping(keycloak);
        if (orgIdSystemIdMapping != null) {
            orgIdSystemIdMapping.getContent().forEach(o -> organizationCacheRepository.saveOrgIdsSystemsIdsMappings(o.getOrgId(), o.getId()));
            logger.debug("Was saved {} orgIds", orgIdSystemIdMapping.getContent().size());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error fetching whole mapping for org and systems ids. Exception: {}", e);
    }
}
}
```

So, in post-construct phase of `OrganizationCacheJob` I want to get `res` when calling `clearingHelper`, but instead I get `null`.

`ClearingHelper` is a regular Spring bean marked as a `@Component` with public methods.

Comment: @Antoniossss done, please have a look. I think code of the bean itself is not that much of a deal, but if you think I should add it too - let me know :)

Comment: What happens when you move `doUpdateCacheRepository()` to the constructor and delete `updateCacheRepository()` method? By the way you [don't need](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection) the `@Autowired` on the constructor.

Comment: I see no `vdvClearingHelper` in test class code. Maybe this is the culrprit.

Comment: Do you mean clearingHelper is null in doUpdateCacheRepository() method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh ok I just realized - when you start your test case, whole env is up and running first, then you advance to testing phase. So, translating to your case - first you got injection and post-constructs called, then `@Before` method is done, thus the result.

So as you can see, code says more than all the words you could put in your original post.

If it is possible for you, use spies insteed of mocks. If it is not possible to construct that, you will have to redesign your tests to not rely on post construct.

In this case, since you want the same post-construct behavior for every test case, provide own factory method for given mock (like you did with keycloak) and move when-doReturn there. It will be guaranteed that it will happen before post construct.

Comment: I ended up providing factory method for mock as you said and it works great. Thank you!